# Datagridview update cell at certain condition

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview, visual-studio-2013

I have a datagrid with column id, nama barang, jumlah, harga

I used a textbox to input the data from database access, but i want update jumlah = jumlah + 1 whenever I inputed another id that already in the datagrid, but I got confused. Already try the for each row and for int count row things

this is my code

```
private void button_Input_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBoxKodeBarang.Text != "")
        {
            insert_Data();
        }
        else if (textBoxKodeBarang.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Kode barang tidak boleh kosong !");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Kode barang yang anda masukan salah !");
        }
    }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }

    private void insert_Data()
    {
        string cmdText = "Insert into [temp_Transaksi] (ID, nama_barang, harga) select id, nama, harga from [barang] where id =@pId";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pId", textBoxKodeBarang.Text);

        conn.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }



   private void update_Data()
    {
        string cmdText = "Update [temp_Transaksi] set jumlah=jumlah+1 where id =@pId";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pId", textBoxKodeBarang.Text);

        conn.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Have you ever seen messagebox popping up with message "Kode barang yang anda masukan salah" ? With your code, it will never execute.

Comment: yes, u right. that why i want to fix them, and change with another code. i want to compare the textbox with the datagridview cell, so whenever there already same id the jumlah column can be updated.

Comment: Already SOLVED, ty ^^